# Add directory structure to SVN, without files

Tags: svn, directory

Is there a way to add a directory structure to an SVN repository without adding the files contained in the folders?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

So sorry, I should've RTFM ...

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html

You can add a directory without adding its contents:

```
$ svn add --depth=empty otherdir
A         otherdir
```

**Edit:** This doesn't work recursively though, is there any way to do that too?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do it recursively, maybe this will work for you?

```
find . -type d ! -name '.' ! -path "*.svn*" -print0 | xargs -0 svn add --depth=empty
```

Comment: The problem is that the "svn add" will automatically recurse and include the contents of the directories.  You'll need to use 'svn add -N' instead I think to ensure that it only works on the directory and not any files inside.

Comment: Oh right, as he said, will edit post

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but

```
svn add --non-recursive
```

works non-recusively.